# Можно ли связать LuaJIT с C#?

Tags: c#, lua

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способ использовать библиотеку LuaJIT в программе, написанной на C# по аналогии с C/C++. Т.е., как вызов Lua функций из C#, так и 'открытие' C# функций и классов для использования в Lua.

Из того, что я вижу, есть NLua, мертвый проект. Но в целях производительности хотелось бы все-таки LuaJIT реализацию.

UPD: Еще есть MoonSharp, это вообще реализация на C#. Опять же, проект мертв.

Comment: Вариант с использованием атрибута _DllIMport_ и модификатора _extern_ вы не рассматриваете?

Comment: Из того, что я понял, открыть C# функции для Lua таким способом не получится. Да и инструкций я не видел толковых.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогу, единственное, что я нашел, был форк проекта Eluant: https://github.com/ModTheGungeon/Eluant

Последнее обновление год назад, в отличии от MoonSharp (в 7-10 раз медленнее обычного Lua, заброшен) и NLua (также мертв).